# Can't make an angular component work with componentRouter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a boilerplate to use angular 1.5.x and components, but it's impossible (for now) make the components work.

Here is my folder structure:

```
rootfolder
  .....
  index.html
  static/
    app/
      components/
        app/
          appBase.js
        hello/
          hello.js
      app.js
      routes.js
      services.js
```

So the idea is simple: take the components apart, with the routes inside them. I'm using the John Papa style guide and Todd Motto.

Here are my modules:

#### app.js (main module)

```
(function() {

 'use strict'
  angular
    .module('app', ['ngComponentRouter', 'app', 'app.hello'])

})();
```

#### routes.js (config file)

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
      .module('app')
      .config(config)
      .value('$routerRootComponent', 'app');

    config.$inject = ['$locationProvider'];

    function config($locationProvider){
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    };

})();
```

#### the components: appBase.js / hello.js in separated folders.

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  var app = {
    template: `
                <hello></hello>
                <ng-outlet></ng-outlet>
              `,
    $routeConfig: [
      { path: '/', name: 'app', component: 'hello' }
    ]
  };

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .component('app', app);

})();

(function() {

  'use strict';

  var hello = {
    template: `<h1>Hello World</h1>`
  };

  angular
    .module('app.hello', [])
    .component('hello', hello);

})();
```

#### The index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Components example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <app></app>

    <script src="static/assets/bower/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="static/assets/bower/bower_components/angular-component-router/angular_1_router.js"></script>
    <script src="static/assets/js/dist/angular-app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no errors in the console, the app module are doing the job:

```
<app>
    <hello></hello>
     <ng-outlet></ng-outlet>
</app>
```

But the `hello` component just doesn't work... any idea?

Comment: Where are your application scripts in index.html?

Comment: All are minified and concated with my gulp tasks in app.min.js

Comment: oh i see now. haha completely missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are not getting any console errors but I think you're overriding your own module definitions here.

try:

```
(function() {

 'use strict'
  angular
    .module('app', ['ngComponentRouter', 'app.hello'])
    .module('app.hello', [])
})();
```

and

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .component('app', app);
```

and

```
angular
    .module('app.hello')
    .component('hello', hello);
```

Comment: So you say that i need to use a "getter" and no set a new module? Like `angular.module('app').component()....`?

Comment: The problem was exactly that! I'm overwriting the `app` module.